# React: Invalid hook call error when i tried wrap App component with Provider

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to React and Redux. I try to learn redux structure. I have a store. I added Provider component to *index.js*
Now, I try wrap App component with Provider. Then pass store to Provider in index.js But I get a typical error which is

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

My index.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import reducer from "./store/reducer";

const store = createStore(reducer);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}> //error show this line
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Also, my reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    code: "initial", //my state which is using in component
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    return state;
};

export default reducer;
```

Help me, please.

Comment: what version of react and react-redux do you use

Comment: react version : 16.13.1, react-dom version: 16.13.1,react-redux version: 7.2.0

Comment: can you include reducer you are using in your post?

Comment: What does your package.json look like? It could be many things causing this so do you have a github project demonstrating this or a [doce sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-lake-g4sn7?file=/src/index.js)?

Comment: Im unable to reproduce the issue, everything should work fine based on provided code. Try to remove node_modules from your working directory and reinstall packages

Comment: You are right. I remove node_modules and reinstall. Its work. Thanks to much. 
I guess I made a mistake somewhere